# Color Blending in WebGL

Tags: fragment, shader, webgl

I'm using the following library:
https://github.com/tengbao/vanta/blob/master/src/vanta.halo.js

A demo can be found here:
https://www.vantajs.com/?effect=halo

If I'm using a bright (or even white) background color, the effect is not visible anymore.
With my limited WebGL knowledge, my guess is that this is because of the subtraction of the background color (`mixedColor = texture2D(...) - backgroundColor`) (but I could be wrong).

```js
void main() {
  vec2 res2 = iResolution.xy * iDpr;
  vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / res2; // 0 to 1

  vec4 oldImage = texture2D(iBuffer, uv);
  vec3 mixedColor = oldImage.rgb - backgroundColor;

  float cropDist = 0.01;
  float cropXOffset = 0.2;
  float cropYOffset = 0.2;

  vec2 offset = uv + vec2((mixedColor.g - cropXOffset) * cropDist, (mixedColor.r - cropYOffset) * cropDist);

  float spinDist = 0.001;
  float spinSpeed = 0.2 + 0.15 * cos(iTime * 0.5);
  float timeFrac = mod(iTime, 6.5);
  vec2 offset2 = uvBig + vec2(cos(timeFrac * spinSpeed) * spinDist, sin(timeFrac * spinSpeed) * spinDist);

  mixedColor = texture2D(iBuffer, offset).rgb * 0.4
    + texture2D(iBuffer, offset2).rgb * 0.6
    - backgroundColor;

  float fadeAmt = 0.0015; // fade this amount each frame // 0.002
  mixedColor = (mixedColor - fadeAmt) * .995;

  vec4 spectrum = abs( abs( .95*atan(uv.x, uv.y) -vec4(0,2,4,0) ) -3. )-1.;
  float angle = atan(pixel.x, pixel.y);
  float dist = length(pixel - mouse2*0.15) * 8. + sin(iTime) * .01;

  float flowerPeaks = .05 * amplitudeFactor * size;
  float flowerPetals = 7.;
  float edge = abs((dist + sin(angle * flowerPetals + iTime * 0.5) * sin(iTime * 1.5) * flowerPeaks) * 0.65 / size);

  float colorChangeSpeed = 0.75 + 0.05 * sin(iTime) * 1.5;
  float rainbowInput = timeFrac * colorChangeSpeed;

  float brightness = 0.7;
  vec4 rainbow = sqrt(j2hue(cos(rainbowInput))) + vec4(baseColor,0) - 1.0 + brightness;
  float factor = smoothstep(1., .9, edge) * pow(edge, 2.);
  vec3 color = rainbow.rgb * smoothstep(1., .9, edge) * pow(edge, 20.);
  vec4 ring = vec4(
    backgroundColor + clamp( mixedColor + color, 0., 1.)
    , 1.0);

  gl_FragColor = ring;
}
```

However I'm not able to figure out, how to adapt the behavior, so I can use a bright background.
If I remove the subtraction (and also remove the addition of the same at the end (`vec4 ring = vec4(clamp(...)`)), I get the correct effect but with a black background.

Does anyone have an idea how to adapt the shader?

Comment: did u figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that `backgroundColor` is being added to the color to calculate the `ring` value. This will blow out your final color if `backgroundColor` is too bright.